# Rails 4 where and select query with custom function

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 and is having a table structure something like this:

```
Order(id: integer, ..., created_at: datetime, states_time: string)
```

Now I want to query the above table based on states_time, forex: to find all orders which are dispatched between time t1 and t2. Given, dispatch time can be computed using a function `get_dispatch_time(x)`.

Hopefully, final where query should be like:

```
Order.all.where(get_dipatch_time: t1..t2) # WRONG SYNTAX
```

similar as:

```
Order.all.where(created_at: t1..t2)
```

I can fetch this data using `select` query and lamda expression, but then again issue is it will return array of ActiveRecord Objects, instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation, and hence further queries (pagination query) can not be executed over it.

```
Order.all.select{ |o| get_dispatch_time(o) > t1 && get_dispatch_time(o) < t2 }
=> #[#<Order id: 10, ship_by: ....>, #<Order id: 2, ..> ]
```

But, instead the required result should be:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Order id: 10, ship_by: ....>, #<Order id: 2, ..> ]>
```

The main issue is one can chain queries only over ActiveRecord::Relation. Forex: `Order.where(...).order(...).sort(...).limit(...)`

Can someone help me with:

1. How to use custom methods with `where` query, returning ActiveRecord::Relation? 
   **OR**
2. How to apply query chain with `select` query in between ?

**EDIT**

Some clarifications:

1. get_dispatch_time(x) is a Ruby function.
2. I need to filter the data based on some custom function f(x), where x is the column name. Forex: if column name `x` is execution_date:DateTime,the f(x) can be something like `2^((execution_date * 1000) + 200)`, just some complex function (and yeah it is really complex !!).
   So, now want to query based on that complex function return value (which is a DateTime)
3. Making query on a column name is easy, my question is How to make query on a custom function. (It is possible for select query by using lambda expression, as I mentioned above. But Is it possible for where query too ? Is there any other way to solve above problem?)

Comment: What does your get_dispatch_time function do? Could you mimic its behaviour in SQL somehow?

Comment: Is `get_dispatch_time` an SQL function or Ruby function? Can you include it in the question?

Comment: `get_dispatch_time` is a Ruby function (basic overview: it iterates over a JSON stringify string (multiple times stringified) and fetch appropriate time in epoch string and then return it as DateTime).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sql functions if you don't know how to use it.

> forex: to find all orders which are dispatched between time t1 and t2

For example you have model `Foo` with column `execution_date:date`. To find all records in `foos` table which has `execution_date` in range of `t1` and `t2` you must to use next query:

```
Foo.where('execution_date > ? OR execution date < ?', t1, t2)
```

This query means 'I am looking for records in foos table which have date in execution_date more than t1 OR less than t2'

Comment: I edited the post to make it more clarify. Firing a query over column name is easy. The problem is to firing it on a custom function, say
`function(Foo.execution_date)`, if execution_date is the column.